# When exporting an org file to html, how do I only get the html body, ignoring other parts?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have an org file I am using to write a webpage. I write it in the org file, then export it to an HTML buffer with <kbd>C-c C-e h H</kbd>. This exports an entire html document, from the `<?xml>` declaration to the `DOCTYPE` to javascript and CSS, to a table of contents, to the ending `</body></html>`.

My problem is that I only want the org file to be a *part* of the final page; there is other static content I want there, and that content is controlled by a separate system. My workflow involves taking the org-exported-html and copying *part* of the resulting html into this second system. This is fine, but I have to manually find the part of the buffer where my content begins, and copy from there to the part of the buffer where my content ends.

Is there a way I can control the "extra" html content org puts into the buffer? It doesn't have to use the org export interface, although it is a convenient way of exporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible exporting body-only "as is" using the following keys:

<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd><kbd>C-b</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>

Note that the only thing it differs from your command is <kbd>C-b</kbd> before the formatting export options.

At least using Emacs 27.0.9 and the last org from melpa.

Comment: Note also that this applies to *any* exporter, not just HTML.

Comment: Very interesting! I wish there was a way to set it by default, but it doesn't look like it.

Comment: @zck I guess your could use either `C-u` to repeat the last export call, or making your own encapsulated command using `org-export-as` specifying your backend and options.